# ubuntu 16.04 install phpmyadmin 404

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Operation system: ubuntu 16.04
Runs in a VWWare Player
I installed Lamp with apache2, php, mysql and it works just fine.

then I installed phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

This installs a lot, but if I open the browser with localhost/phpmyadmin I get the 404 Error: Page not found.

I searched for other ways: I was told to just copy the phpmyadmin.***.tar file to the document_root folder. This works, but I don't have access to the Database. I get the User/PWD Dialog but I haven't set anything, so I don't know the password

I would like to get some help on the "sudo install phpmyadmin" way, which seems to me to be the right one.

Regards Martin

Answer (score 2):

I read about some changes up from ubuntu 13
The following did the trick:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that I could open localhost/phpmyadmin (But I forgot the password)
So I removed phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
```

and simply reinstalled it:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

User name is phpmyadmin and the password has to be set during the installation

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest installing this manually so it's up to date and as secure as possible.

cd to webroot

IE: cd /var/www/html

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.7/phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages.zip && unzip phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages.zip
```

Make sure unzip + wget are installed.

```
apt-get install wget unzip
```

I also suggest renaming the phpmyadmin dir.

```
mv phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages random-name-here
```

Comment: Either tar or zip copies of course the same sets into my document_root. The problem remains the same. After opening  localhost/random-name-here (i.e.)   I can see the login sceen. But what is the username / password?

Comment: The password is something you set, during the install for mysql it prompts you for a password. If you need to reset it try this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: Whatever I try; I get this errror

Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Is mysql running? "service mysql status" if not you may need to start it.

Comment: Hello ajankuv, I found another solution and posted it as answer. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried root with no password?
 Sorry I'm not allowed to add this as comment.